# Elastisearch Failed to JSON encode issue

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I working on elastic search and I have 1K phone numbers when I pass this phone numbers array to elastic search to search users through phone numbers it gives me exception

```
Failed to JSON encode /var/app/current/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Serializers/SmartSerializer.php
```

Below is my Elasticsearch client initializing

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts([$host])->build();
```

And my working query in Elasticsearch

```
{
  "_source": [
    "id"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "user"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "phone": {
                    "value": "923047698099"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "prefix": {
                  "phone": {
                    "value": "92313730320"
                  }
                }
              },
              .
              .
              .
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "blocked",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "u-2"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "block",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "u-2"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "db_id": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know that where I doing mistake. Either at client initializing or writing elasticserch query. I searched this issue but not usefull solution found or might be I did't understand clearly. But still I am stucked on this issue that how to solve this problem. Suggest any usefull link or solution.
Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information here to help. What are you trying to `json_encode` and where? Does `SmartSerializer` do that? Then what data are you passing it to? What's in `$host`?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I mentioned my query in question when I pass this query to my elasticsearch client then It give me exception and there is more than 900+ condition in should condition.

Comment: Why are you using `prefix` query? Why don't you use `terms` query instead?